# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 on HP Elite book 840 G3

Tags: system-installation, hp

I have been trying in last 7 days to install Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 LTS on my HP Elite book 840 G3 laptop but it's not installing.

It fails after it has been given the username, password, the time zone; when it's copying files and than its stuck and no progress is made.

I see in the processing file it's showing error types of message in terminal processing file.

Now what should I do for successfully install the Ubuntu?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late but:- I had issues booting Ubuntu 19.10 on my HP 840 G3 until I updated the BIOS. It was a problem related to the APIC being configured by the BIOS at startup.

BIOS update fixed it.

I hope this helps someone.